# How to change css color to match bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a new css class with the same background color as bootstrap uses for "bg-primary". I've read the documentation and under SASS it says that I should be able to use the color as a variable in other CSS files, but I'm not sure how.

I want to do something like this:

```css
.my_css_class{
    background-color: bg-primary;
}
```

I've seen some questions in stack that suggest importing a lot of files, but I have the feeling there should be an easier way.

Comment: To be clear, in your own files you are using CSS and not Sass/SCSS, correct?

Comment: Correct. I'm not used to using Sass...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I am interpreting your question correctly and you are using CSS (as opposed to Sass/SCSS), the easiest thing you could do would be to use [CSS custom properties (basically native CSS variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).  It turns out [Bootstrap provides CSS custom properties for the theme colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/colors/), so you should be able to write this as:

```
.my_css_class{
    background-color: var(--bs-primary);
}
```

Comment: Nice. New to me.

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what i was looking for. ¡Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnaCruz - Glad this helped; happy coding!